# How to create text selection menu use action PROCESS_TEXT with icons on my android app?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I want to create text selection menu use action PROCESS_TEXT show on other apps

but the menu show without icon

```
     <activity
            android:name=".UppercaseActivity"
            android:label="To Upper"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

how to create icon
[image]

```
       <activity
            android:name=".UppercaseActivity"
            android:label="To Upper"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The icon did not appear

Comment: That is not currently supported by the platform classes. The only thing from the `<activity>` that's used to create the visual menu item is the `android:label`, and the `MenuItem` itself is `SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER`, so it's always in the overflow popup.